# Mongoose - Why might model.find() trigger JSON TypeError in basic server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**NodeJS Version**: 10.16.0

**Express Version**: 4.17.1

**Mongoose Version**: 5.6.9

I'm using the following, simplified database server with Postman. The `app.post('/')` route allows a user to add documents to the database.  It works as expected.

The `app.get('/')` route should send the contents of the database to the user.  This triggers an error and does not work as expected.  `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.  I'm following a tutorial and I can't understand what is triggering this error.  Being new to MongoDB I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

```
"use strict";

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv/config');

const app = express();

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true
    }
});

let Posts = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let outputTest = Posts.find();  //this is where I'm having the problem.
    res.send(outputTest);  //this is where I'm having the problem.
});

app.post('/', bodyParser.json(), (req, res, next) => {
    const currentPost = new Posts({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    });

    currentPost.save()
        .then()
        .catch();

    console.log();
    res.send('posted');
});

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(connectSuccess)
    .catch(connectFailure);

function connectSuccess(client) {
    console.log('connected');
}   

function connectFailure(err) {
    console.log(Error, err);
}

app.listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Posts.find()` is asynchronous so it hasn't finished when you send the response. To solve it, you can:

1.Use callback:

```
Posts.find({}, function(err, outputTest) {
  if (err) // handle error
  else res.send(outputTest);
});
```

2.Use `async/await` with `try/catch` to handle error:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let outputTest = await Posts.find();  
    res.send(outputTest);
  } catch(err) {
    // handle error
  }
});
```